# Opening folder via vba not working without null string append

Tags: excel, vba

There must be some witchcraft here: of the following 3 apparently identical ways to open a folder in a file browser, only the second two work, the first way will not work.

```
CreateObject("Shell.Application").Open path$
CreateObject("Shell.Application").Open path$ & ""
CreateObject("Shell.Application").Open "C:"
```

Any possible reason why?

Comment: For me, `Path$` returns nothing, and `CreateObject("Shell.Application").Open path$` does nothing.  While `CreateObject("Shell.Application").Open path$ & ""` does the exact same thing as `CreateObject("Shell.Application").Open ""`

Comment: What is the value of `path$`?

Comment: Shell typically prefers variants to Strings, so maybe that's the issue.